# Is there a reliable Command Line or Powershell step format to run RSpec tests on TeamCity?

Tags: ruby, powershell, rspec, continuous-integration, teamcity

We are experimenting with using RSPec for our UI tests and noted that while attempting to integrate these with TeamCity we end up with environment related errors. The problem is that when we run these tests locally on the build server they run without any errors.

We are trying to execute the login test within a working directory located on the build server with a Command Line or Powershell:

```
cd D:\web_smoke_tests-master
gem install bundler
rake cloud:chrome
```

We are returning the following error in our build log despite the environment containing all of the ruby dependencies. Note that this is a windows build server / build agent.

```
[21:31:30]Step 3/5: Execute login test (Command Line)
[21:31:30][Step 3/5] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script #edited out
[21:31:30][Step 3/5] in directory: D:\web_smoke_tests-master
[21:31:30][Step 3/5] 'gem' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[21:31:30][Step 3/5] operable program or batch file.
[21:31:30][Step 3/5] 'rake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[21:31:30][Step 3/5] operable program or batch file.
[21:31:30][Step 3/5] Process exited with code 1
[21:31:30][Step 3/5] Step Execute login test (Command Line) failed
```

Comment: Is your TeamCity agent service running under system account?  System account environment variables differ from the user account that you are probably using for testing.

Comment: Thanks, this issue was indeed due to the ruby dependencies not being installed on the user that contained the build agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the above. This was due to the user containing the build agent not having any ruby dependencies installed and as a result "gem" or "rake" were not recognized.